# Mapping generic Many-Many with custom key names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entity2> Entity2s { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMapping 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentKey { get; set; }
    public EntityType ParentType { get; set; }
    public Guid ChildKey { get; set; }
    public EntityType ChildType { get; set; }
}
```

I would need to do something with the fluent configuration API to perform:

```
select e2.* from Entity1 e1
join Entitymapping em on em.ParentKey == e1.EntityKey && em.ParentType == 'Entity1'
join Entity2 e2 on em.ChildKey == e2.EntityKey
```

when I call: `entity1.Entity2s.ToList()`

Is this is even possible with just the fluent configurations in EF 4?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, first.  Why are you not using the Id field as your Primary?  Maintained by SQL Server as unique, etc, etc.  Two keys per entity is asking for trouble.

Pretty much same M-M answer as I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034928/reference-child-entity-with-multiple-common-parents/49035449#49035449)

Your entities need some work.  Entity1/Entity2 navigation properties should point to List<EntityMapping> and EntityMapping should point to one each of Entity1 & Entity2.  It's a Join table of 1-1 where each side could be many, thus Many-to-Many.  If you want all Entity1's and their associated Entity2's that would be more like this:

DbSet.Entity1.Include("EntityMapping").Include("EntityMapping.Entity2").ToList();

Using a single table to store relationships between many different entities still doable with similar structure.  There will be some "behind-the-scenes" checks to enforce 1-1 or 1-M relationships into the M-M mold, bet this should get you started...

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }
    public EntityType E1Type { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityMapping> Entity2s { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }
    public EntityType E2Type { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityMapping> Entity1s { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMapping 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentKey { get; set; }
    public int ChildKey { get; set; }
    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

For all entities called "Foo" and the "Bar" child entities (assuming Foo could also be related to "Widgets"  There is an EF "way" to do that but the SQL SELECT you're shooting for is

```
select e1.EntityKey as e1Key, e2.EntityKey as e2Key from Entity1 e1
inner join EntityMapping e3 on e3.ParentKey = e1.Id
inner join Entity2 e2 on e2.Id = e3.ChildKey
where e1.E1Type = "Foo" and e2.E2Type = "Bar"
```

EF-speak

```
var temp = DbSet.Entity1.Select(p => p.E1Type == "Foo").Include("EntityMapping").Include("EntityMapping.Entity2");
var result = temp.Where(r => r.E2Type == "Bar").ToList();
```

Could probably combine those but I'd have to tinker instead of "off the cuff".  That better?

Comment: EF Loading reference more like DbSet.Entity2.ToList().

Comment: It is not using the primary because this mapping table is being reused for many different types of entities

Comment: Ok, so the Guid is merely data, NOT a key.  And therefore NOT to be used in relationships.  Example is accurate.

Comment: Thought: Or are you saying there are MANY different Entity1/Entity2 tables that are sharing this join method?

Comment: This is a massive legacy application and we had to abstract out our addresses into "spaces". We can access everything through our repositories but it would be much nicer to just reference the type directly in the Domain class and have the configuration take care of the joins. Bottom line is this is how our architecture looks and I just need to know if this is doable with the fluent API. I dont care if its "correct"...

Comment: I couldnt find anything in the configuration API `map` to explicitly define column join `pair names` on both left and right.

Comment: And yes there are MANY different entity1/entity2 tables using this join. That is why there is `ParentType` and `ChildType`

Comment: I dont think you understand. Yes your new example structure is correct BUT I am trying to have the fluent configurations handle the join query for me... I just want to be able to call `entity1.Entity2s.ToList()` and have it return all the mapped entities automatically without an explicit include query

Comment: Oh, I understand.  I was pointing out what is required.  The format you are asking for is NOT how EF works.  Sorry about that.