# Can someone explain to me how this LINQ/Entity Framework query actually works?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm pretty new to Entity Framework, and today I've been looking for a way to have a condition on the navigation properties I include.  Basically all of my entities are 'flagged' as deleted in the database rather than being actually deleted, so I wanted my WebAPI to return all of the 'parent' objects that aren't flagged as deleted, but also only include their nested navigation properties that haven't been deleted as well.

The solution I keep finding, which does work, is this (after temporarily disabling lazy loading for my context):

```
var projectQuery = await db.Projects.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Select(x => new
            {
                Project = x,
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description,
                Owner = x.Owner,
                Sponsor = x.Sponsor,
                DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
                DateOpened = x.DateOpened,
                DateClosed = x.DateClosed,
                IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,
                CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
                Expenses = x.Expenses.Where(y => !y.IsDeleted),
                TimeEntries = x.TimeEntries.Where(y => !y.IsDeleted)
            }).ToListAsync();

            results = projectQuery.Select(x => Mapper.Map<ProjectDto>(x.Project)).ToList();
```

Obviously I can follow the general idea of what's going on, i.e. throwing the results into anonymous objects so that I'm able to specify a Where condition on the child collections (Expenses and TimeEntries).  My confusion comes from my need of getting the objects back to their original type... the original object itself is included as a property of each anonymous object I'm creating, and is then used as the 'final' object which I can map back to my DTOs or whatever else I need.

What black magic is this? How the heck does this object reference seemingly know to use the properties I've defined in the anonymous object as its own properties? I really would've expected the Project property to be exactly the same as the Project I'm getting from my DbContext and was shocked to find out that it does in fact work.  I found this as a solution to my problem from several sources, none of which actually provided some insight as to what's going on here

Comment: So are you saying that the `Project` in your anonymous class has it's `Expenses` and `TimeEntries` properly filtered and you want to know why?

Comment: @juharr Yes, exactly.

Comment: Expresison Trees and reflection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx

Comment: Actually the `projectQuery` contains a lot of redundant code and most probably is not needed at all - AutoMapper `ProjectTo` would do the same with less effort and more efficiently.

Comment: AutoMapper would not be more efficient.

Comment: @MatthewWhited The question is about loading entity navigation properties with filtered data. Looking at your answer and the above comment, you are missing that point at all. And using AutoMapper to perform the whole projection of course is more efficient because it would eliminate the need of the intermediate list with bunch of data that is not used in the `results`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Honestly, the question was just about how the code works as written, which I think MatthewWhited has addressed.  I'm brand-spanking-new to AutoMapper as well and admittedly haven't looked into it aside from a straight conversion from Entity to DTO and back.  For the purposes of my project I'll give it a bit more research, but for the purposes of this question I think I'm happy with the direction he's provided

Comment: @McFixit I'm glad that you find the answer helpful. I personally don't see how it explains the black magic of loading `Expenses` and `TimeEntries`, which has nothing in common with expression trees and SQL generation, but EF tracking and navigation property fixup. And all that tricks are unnecessary when all you need is to project to DTOs. Anyway, my comments are mostly for future readers, the code (and post) is all yours :)

Comment: That is handled via the expression tree.  if you look at the Expresison Tree passed into the Select function you will see it is just passing in the entity object for the projection. You can project into pretty much any .Net object as I mentioned in my comment below.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not trying to be dismissive in any way, I'll definitely be looking more into AutoMapper and the points you've made :) I was mostly just curious how this wackiness works 'under the hood', specifically the object being passed in as a property and magically coming out as defined by the rest of the anonymous object. Are you saying he's wrong that I should be looking into how EF uses Expression Trees to explain this?

Comment: You'd better look here [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232) - *Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities* section because what really makes your query work is similar to that. Also [Materialize entity framework query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011515/materialize-entity-framework-query) and in general - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5Drelationship+fixup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF is using [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx) to parse your queries.  By passing in the original entity it can see what is being assigned where on the new object graph and then use that information to build an equivalent database query.  When the query is executed it is also projected into the object structure you defined.

The mapping and projection is why only a limited set of .Net functions may be ran within the EF query

Comment: "Anonymous" type not being so anonymous for EF isin't it ? As long as it can reconize the structure, it works.

Comment: Anonymous types are still normal .Net objects. The compiler will even use the same type within the same assembly if the structures are the same.  But the part of EF that does the magic is based on expression trees.  You can project into any .Net object as long as it has parameterless constructor.

Comment: Magic, got it :) 

Obviously I've got some reading to do in order to actually wrap my head around this, but looks like you've pointed me in the right direction, thanks!